# What is the meaning of "everything else I do"?

Tags: noun-phrases

> Julie: So I'll cook my way through the Julia Child cookbook and write
>   a blog about it. But I'll probably need a deadline.
>
> Eric: Why?
>
> Julie: Because otherwise it'll be like **everything else I do**.  'Cause
>   let's face it, I never finish anything.

Is Julie saying that she will do cooking except everything?

Comment: Please provide the source of this text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Everything else I do* = “all the other things which I do&rdquo

The simple present here has a ‘generic’ sense: it does not designate merely the immediately present moment but a more-or-less permanent state of affairs, as when we say *The Earth goes round the Sun*.

If Julie doesn't set herself a deadline for writing the blog, she will not finish it, just as she fails to finish all of the activities she undertakes.